# unknown type name 'ACameraDevice' in ndk

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, android

I want develop opencv programs in android with NDK, for that I tried to build [this](https://github.com/sjfricke/OpenCV-NDK) sample project in android studio but when made project these errors occur :

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process E:\SoftWare\Android\android-ndk-r19c\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\127051\Documents\StudioProjects\StudioProjects\ImageProccessing\app\src\main\cpp\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\127051\Documents\StudioProjects\StudioProjects\ImageProccessing\app\src\main\cpp\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86_64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86_64 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\127051\Documents\StudioProjects\StudioProjects\ImageProccessing\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib APP_CPPFLAGS+=-std=c++14 C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86_64/libopencv_ndk.so}

[x86_64] Compile++      : opencv_ndk <= native-lib.cpp

In file included from C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:4:
In file included from C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/src/main/cpp/CV_Main.h:15:
C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/src/main/cpp/Native_Camera.h:15:55: error: unknown type name 'ACameraDevice'
static void CameraDeviceOnDisconnected(void* context, ACameraDevice* device) {
                                                      ^
C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/src/main/cpp/Native_Camera.h:18:48: error: unknown type name 'ACameraDevice'
static void CameraDeviceOnError(void* context, ACameraDevice* device,
                                               ^
C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/src/main/cpp/Native_Camera.h:25:35: error: unknown type name 'ACameraCaptureSession'
                                  ACameraCaptureSession* session) {
                                  ^
C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/src/main/cpp/Native_Camera.h:29:36: error: unknown type name 'ACameraCaptureSession'
                                   ACameraCaptureSession* session) {
                                   ^
C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/src/main/cpp/Native_Camera.h:52:3: error: unknown type name 'ACameraDevice'
  ACameraDevice* m_camera_device;
  ^
C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/src/main/cpp/Native_Camera.h:53:3: error: unknown type name 'ACaptureRequest'
  ACaptureRequest* m_capture_request;
  ^
C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/src/main/cpp/Native_Camera.h:54:3: error: unknown type name 'ACameraOutputTarget'
  ACameraOutputTarget* m_camera_output_target;
  ^
C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/src/main/cpp/Native_Camera.h:55:3: error: unknown type name 'ACaptureSessionOutput'
  ACaptureSessionOutput* m_session_output;
  ^
C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/src/main/cpp/Native_Camera.h:56:3: error: unknown type name 'ACaptureSessionOutputContainer'
  ACaptureSessionOutputContainer* m_capture_session_output_container;
  ^
C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/src/main/cpp/Native_Camera.h:57:3: error: unknown type name 'ACameraCaptureSession'
  ACameraCaptureSession* m_capture_session;
  ^
C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/src/main/cpp/Native_Camera.h:59:3: error: unknown type name 'ACameraDevice_StateCallbacks'
  ACameraDevice_StateCallbacks m_device_state_callbacks;
  ^
C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/src/main/cpp/Native_Camera.h:60:3: error: unknown type name 'ACameraCaptureSession_stateCallbacks'
  ACameraCaptureSession_stateCallbacks m_capture_session_state_callbacks;
  ^
C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/src/main/cpp/Native_Camera.h:62:3: error: unknown type name 'ACameraManager'
  ACameraManager* m_camera_manager;
  ^
C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/src/main/cpp/Native_Camera.h:64:3: error: unknown type name 'ACameraIdList'
  ACameraIdList* m_camera_id_list = NULL;
  ^
14 errors generated.
make: *** [C:/Users/127051/Documents/StudioProjects/StudioProjects/ImageProccessing/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86_64/objs-debug/opencv_ndk/native-lib.o] Error 1
```

**Environment Details:**

NDK Version: r19c

Host OS: Windows

IDE: Android Studio 3.3.2

SDK Platform Tools : 28.0.2

SDK Tools : 25.2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use native camera2 API, set your **APP_PLATFORM** to **android-24** or higher. In Android Studio, this corresponds to **minSdkVersion** in `build.gradle` script.